# SQL Query to retrieve records whose status got changed

Tags: sql-server

there is some error in our data, and we are trying to pull all the error records from our database. See below example:

```
select * from students where studentID = 555 order by TimeStamp desc

StudentID   StatusID    Status                     TimeStamp
555          2         Registered for Subject A    2017-08-01 01:00:00
555          3         Passed Subject A            2017-07-30 01:00:00
555          2         Registered for Subject A    2017-05-10 01:00:00
555          1         New Student                 2017-05-01 01:00:00
```

For one Student `StudentID = 555`, he already Passed Subject A(see row 2), which should be the final status, but someone went manually and updated the status again back to '2' --> "Registered for Subject A"(which is incorrect). There are many such students who got impacted. We wanted to run a query and fetch all records whose status got changed from '3' to any other statuses like 2,1,....
It would be great if someone provide an example query. Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the *students*, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select studentid
from t
group by studentid
having max(case when statusid = 3 then timestamp end) < max(timestamp);
```

If you want the detailed records that are after the "3", use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(case when statusid = 3 then timestamp end) as timestamp_3
      from t
     ) t
where timestamp > timestamp_3;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to retrieve all the problematic records, Appreciate your help. Thank you :)